# win 11 how to sound through speakers without removing headphones

Tags: audio, windows-11, headphones

In my win 11 `system>sound` both my speakers and headphones play through "speakers", realtek audio.  The speakers are plugged into back, and headphones into front of machine. I used to be able to select my sound output between speakers and headphones without unplugging headphones. But I reset my machine and now it doesn't work as they both use the same sound output there is nothing to change to. To get speakers to play I need to physically remove my headphones.  Is there a way to split them so I can select one or other exclusive of if I unplug the headphones or not?
I seem to remember following something last time on a realtek preferences/option but I cant find any tutorials now...

Comment: Do the speakers work if you right-click the Volume Control icon on the taskbar and select Sounds, Playback tab, right-click the Speakers and then Set as Default Device.

Comment: the speakers is the default device.  But both headphones and speakers play through this sound device.  So speakers plays through headphones when they are plugged in and through my speakers when unplug headphones.  They used to be separate sound options/devices

Comment: So the question is actually how to separate the headphones and speakers devices. What are your computer model and sound adapter?

Comment: I dont really know how to get that info.  Device manager says AMD high definition audio device, and its a ryzen 5, win 11 22621

Comment: Based on your comment I found this - https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-to-separate-this-into-two-devices-instead-it/7970f161-bb53-4874-9f9b-c39412f9d8de  But I dont have  Realtek HD Audio Manager.  maybe I can just download it and do it that way

Comment: the download is >.5 GB Is there a way to do it without a new app?